# How to add and edit user in rest server

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a simple rest server. I can see all users from DB and find a user by id or name.

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "admin", path = "admins")
public interface AdminRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Admin, Long>{

    List<Admin> findByName(@Param("name") String name);

    @Query("SELECT a.name from Admin a where a.id = :id")
    Admin findNameById(@Param("id") Long id);
}
```

How to add and edit user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update a record you can use the item resource URL for the object, for example `http://localhost:8080/admins/1` and send a PUT request to it, containing a JSON representation of your object as the request body, like this:

#### `PUT http://localhost:8080/admins/1` :

```
{
  "name": "New name"
}
```

To create a new object you use a POST request to the collection URL, (for example `http://localhost:8080/admins`). The same rules apply to the request body:

#### `POST http://localhost:8080/admins`:

```
{
  "name": "Name of new object"
}
```

These operations are accessible by default, no other code has to be written.

Related documentation:

- [Collection resource/Supported HTTP methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-resources.collection-resource)
- [Item resource/Supported HTTP methods](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_supported_http_methods_2)

---

Be aware, since you're using HATEOAS, the proper way to determine what the item resource URL is (for updating an object) is by going to the collection, since this resource also contains links to the other resources, for example:

```
{
  "_embedded" : {
    "admin" : [ {
      "name" : "Test 1 2 3 4",
      "_links" : {
        "self" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/admins/1"
        },
        "admin" : {
          "href" : "http://localhost:8080/admins/1"
        }
      }
    }, ...]
  }
}
```

In this case, the property `_links.self.href` contains the reference to the item resource URL, which you should use for updating.

Comment: when I try create a new user I get this error:

`{
  "cause": null,
  "message": "No suitable HttpMessageConverter found to read request body into object of type class com.ubr.model.Admin from request with content type of text/plain;charset=UTF-8!"
}`

Comment: You'll also have to add the header `Content-Type: application/json`.

Comment: edit and delete works, but cannot create. When I write `{"name: "new name"}` I have duplicate key, when I write `{ "id": "4" "name": "new name"}` - have another error `Could not read document: Unexpected character ('"' (code 34)): was expecting comma to separate OBJECT entries
 at [Source: org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteInputStream@24a7db50; line: 3, column: 4];`

Comment: It should be valid JSON. `{ "id": "4" "name": "new name"}` is not valid JSON. The duplicate key sounds like a constraint in the database, that's another issue.

Comment: Thank you for all! I've lost comma )

Answer (score 0):

Spring repository has pre-defined methods to save, update and delete,so we can use them, but to use them, we need to inject the repository in the class as i did below:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

public class AdminResource {

    @Autowired // inject the Repository in the class
    private AdminRepository adminRepository;

    public void createAdmin(Admin admin) {

        adminRepository.save(admin);// same you can use for update
    }

    public void deleteAdmin(Admin admin) {
            adminRepository.delete(admin);
    }

}
```

Comment: done. How can I do crud from browser? I mean, when I want to see all users I type in the browser: localhost:8080/admins

Comment: This is a different question, please try to close this one, and add another question explaining the technology you want to use in web (i.e Rest service)

Comment: @SafwanHijazi, that's actually his question, he's using Spring Data REST, which allows you to automatically create REST API's based on your repository.